# display a 16-bit grayscale images from a thermal camera in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to display a 16-bit grayscale images from a thermal camera in OpenCV. I tried different images' encoding but what I get is either totally black or totally white picture. my code looks like this:

```
void imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& img)
{
             cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;
             cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(img);
             cv::imshow("16-bit Mono", cv_ptr->image);
             cv::waitKey(1);
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321107/display-a-16-bit-grayscale-images-from-a-thermal-camera-in-opencv/) by [Khalaf90](https://answers.ros.org/users/40878/khalaf90/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2019-04-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

in case that someone face the same problem in the future, the solution is to convert from 16 bit to 8 bit per pixel using:

```
  cv::normalize(img,img,0.,255.,cv::NORM_MINMAX,CV_8U);
```

---

Originally posted by [Khalaf90](https://answers.ros.org/users/40878/khalaf90/) with karma: 26 on 2019-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gomimaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/145397/gomimaker/) on 2023-04-17**:
Thank you.